# Console Producer Error after Implementing with TLS/SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, tls1.2

I wanted to add TLS/SSL to my kafka setup. To start with, I went through the kafka SSL documenation on main website. I have done the following:

1) Imported the signed certificates to keystore

2) Imported the root CA

3) Verified that the keystore and trust store password are correct by using keytool.

4) Started zookeeper and kafka.

5) Confirmed the following from server.log file:

```
 Registered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0 with addresses: 
EndPoint(localhost,9092,ListenerName(PLAINTEXT),PLAINTEXT),EndPoint(localhost,9093,ListenerName(SSL),SSL) (kafka.utils.ZkUtils)
```

my server.properties file have both listeners and advertised.listeners set to the following:

```
PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093
```

I also have automatic topic creation enabled. When I do:

kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic test_ssl --producer.config ....\config\producer.properties

I am getting the following error:

```
[2017-08-04 16:28:15,265] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {test_ssl=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-08-04 16:28:15,372] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {test_ssl=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-08-04 16:28:15,474] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {test_ssl=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-08-04 16:28:20,302] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3 : {test_ssl=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-08-04 16:28:20,406] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {test_ssl=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-08-04 16:28:20,512] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5 : {test_ssl=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

I tried to print out the SSL comms data using openssl

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:9093 -debug -tls1 // default kafka broker configs have tlsv1 included
```

I get the following:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=GB/ST=Unknown/L=London/O=SOAPYSUDS/OU=SOAPYSUDS/CN=M. Manna
   i:/C=GB/ST=Some-State/L=London/O=SOAPYSUDS/OU=SOAPYSUDS/CN=localhost/emailAddress=xyz@xyz.com
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Some-State/L=London/O=SOAPYSUDS/OU=SOAPYSUDS/CN=localhost/emailAddress=xyz@xyz.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Some-State/L=London/O=SOAPYSUDS/OU=SOAPYSUDS/CN=localhost/emailAddress=xyz@xyz.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=GB/ST=Unknown/L=London/O=SOAPYSUDS/OU=SOAPYSUDS/CN=M. Manna
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Some-State/L=London/O=SOAPYSUDS/OU=SOAPYSUDS/CN=localhost/emailAddress=xyz@xyz.com
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=GB/ST=Some-State/L=London/O=SOAPYSUDS/OU=SOAPYSUDS/CN=localhost/emailAddress=xyz@xyz.com
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5048 bytes and written 285 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
New, TLSv1.0, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 59884152B1D0B4716F30AC8E43BAC10EBBE92E6BD771AAAD31046035564F2B30
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 124F0A4796CCE67A696105F4F88798CFC31E76885DEDF3EB1F702EA565543462AB1CCC9B4E6D726BD7489C17ED77C744
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1502101842
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

Even though the above has error in "Self-signed certificate verification" I think this is common if the CA cert is self signed. Possibly, it is working since SSL Handshake has written/read data.

I can confirm from kafka-topics command (also, server.log) that the topic "test_ssl" creation was successful. I hope it's not because of this underscore "_".

If there was a handshake issue, it would have been caught in the logs (I think, unless the logger is turned off), but it looks like my SSL config has been accepted correctly. Just wanted to know if I have missed something which I cannot quite spot here.

**Note** - I am not using any SSL/TLS with my Zookeeper. Also, because I am starting the TLS tests locally, I am using a common trust store for now (cacerts in jre/lib/security).

-- my client SSL config

```
advertised.listeners=SSL://localhost:9093
listeners=SSL://localhost:9093
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=$java_path/jre/lib/security/cacerts
ssl.truststore.password=changeit
ssl.keystore.location=/kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1/config/kafka_client.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
```

-- my server SSL related properties

```
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
ssl.keystore.location=/kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1/config/kafka_server.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
ssl.truststore.location=$java_path/jre/lib/security/cacerts
ssl.truststore.password=changeit
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
ssl.secure.random.implementation=SHA1PRNG
ssl.client.auth=required
```

fraction of my server logs after startup (with SSL debug enabled):

```
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(SSL)-SSL-0, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(SSL)-SSL-0, called closeOutbound()
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(SSL)-SSL-0, closeOutboundInternal()
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
[Raw write]: length = 7
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
0000Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
: 15Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
 03Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
03 00Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
02 02Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
 50*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
```

I am not sure what configuration I am missing to get this working. I don't think there is anything wrong in my certificate import order since I have confirmed my methods by matching with instructions [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/).

Regards,

Comment: Might be helpful to enable security logging as documented here http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/ssl.html#enabling-ssl-logging

Comment: @HansJespersen         I did and all I can see is all certificates being printed out. As soon as I opened the console-producer and start writing something, it prints certificate non-stop. I am trying to make sense out of it. I also ran `openssl s_client -debug -connect localhost:9093 -tls1`. I cannot see any issue with the certififcates. Also, the order in which I imported the root CA and server signed certificates is correct. Is there any specific things I should look for in the security logs?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention - I did use this too - https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/

Comment: Enabling DEBUG via tools-log4j.properties might also help. The security debug will help if it's a certificate problem. If your certs are printed, you might be good from a cert prospective but missing a config somewhere else. Another tactic would be to make sure that plaintext port works on the broker to rule out a problem with the broker talking to itself.

Answer (score 1):

It was just one config - but I wish there was slightly longer explanation on the documentation for this - but still my bad.

[documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_ssl_key)

`ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm`

I set it to HTTPS - this means that my client will verify my Fully Qualified Domain Name FQDN against one of the following:

1) Common Name (CN)

2) Subject Alternative Name (SAN)

when I created my ceritificate, I was being polite and added my first and last name thinking "That's my first and last names". Since my original certificates didn't have either of the following:

1) `localhost` as CN

2) `localhost` as a DNS

The clients couldn't verify the broker's FQDN against the presented certificate's SAN/CN values. I believe this was the reason since I got it to work after issuing a new self-signed SAN certificate (and importing them into client trust store).